# Identify central European ground cover

Tags: identification, ground-cover

I'd like to know what the green ground plant is. It grows very densely and has some sort of flowers under the leaves. It grows in central Europe.

[image: Ground plant]

Comment: We have a "one plant per id question" policy; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for details. Please post a new question for the second plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The groundcover is a hardy ginger, asarum species most likely (A. europaeus?).

Comment: Hi. We have a "one plant per id question" policy; see https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/826/for-identification-please-only-post-one-plant-per-question-and-be-specific-whe for details. I've edited out one plant id from the question, and updated your post to match. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thats it, awesome! Thank you.